# Lost in an infinite loop

Tags: prolog

I am working on a program that has a problem. In this short example the error is the same:

**EDIT**  **Code was wrong**

```
does_something(A, [Num], Sol) :-
    sort([Num|A], Sol).

correct(Solution) :-
    Solution = [1,2,3,4,5].

pred1(_, Solution, Solution) :- correct(Solution), !.
pred1(A, B, Solution) :-
    member(Num, A),
    does_something(B, [Num], B_aux),
    pred1(A, B_aux, Solution).
```

**Last EDIT:** What I want has nothing to do with the predicates does_something and correct. Those are here just for the example, but it what those do have nothing to do with the problem. What I want is to know if calling the predicate does_something with Num gives the right solution. If it doesn't it's suposed to try another member of A until it finds a solution. If it never does it fails, no problem. My problem is that I can't make does_something to be called with another Num than the first in A.

```
?- pred1([1,2,3], [], S).

Call: (9) [user] does_something([1], [1], _G6045) ? creep
Call: (10) [system] sort([1, 1], _G6047) ? creep
Exit: (10) [system] sort([1, 1], [1]) ? creep
Exit: (9) [user] does_something([1], [1], [1]) ? creep
Call: (9) [user] pred1([1, 2, 3], [1], _G5943) ? creep
Call: (10) [user] correct([1]) ? creep
Call: (11) [system] [1]=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ? creep
Fail: (11) [system] [1]=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ? creep
Fail: (10) [user] correct([1]) ? creep
Redo: (9) [user] pred1([1, 2, 3], [1], _G5943) ? creep
Call: (10) [lists] lists:member(_G6052, [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
Exit: (10) [lists] lists:member(1, [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
Call: (10) [user] does_something([1], [1], _G6057) ? creep
```

The first and last lines of that trace part are equal.

Comment: Can you show the trace? The full source of the program might help too. But ideally, you should attempt to find a minimal, complete example that still reproduces your error. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will try and build an example

Comment: Please show the **entire* program! Otherwise it's all second guessing.

Comment: I have got an example where the error is the same, should I change my post?

Comment: What is the query that you entered? It is somewhat important...

Answer (score 3):

The obvious problem is that your `A` doesn't change, which means that at each step of the recursion, you keep on calling `member(_GXXX, [1, 2, 3])`, and this will invariably pick the first element, 1. On the other end, you keep on adding to a list and sorting, but you only add 1 and sort, so your `B` stays at `[1]`.

This is what your code does. What you intended to achieve is another question, and I can't really guess your intentions from looking at this code :-(

BTW, this:

```
append(A, [X], A1), sort(A1, B)
```

should have the same effect as

```
sort([X|A], B)
```

with the small difference that you don't have to traverse the list when you use `append/3`. (`append/3` should really have been called something else, as using it to append lists is usually unnecessary. It is useful for splitting though...)

PS: if you want to keep on taking one element from a list, the easiest is to pick the first element. A predicate that does that looks something like this:

```
foo([], Result, ...).
foo([X|Xs], R, ...) :-
    foo(Xs, [X|R], ...).
```

So you just pick one element and put it in the other list. You don't need `member/2` for this. Alternatively, you could use `select/3`, which not only gets an element, but also gives you the list of remaining items. However, this:

```
bar([], R, ...).
bar(Xs, R, ...) :-
    select(X, Xs, Xs0),
    bar(Xs0, [X|R], ...).
```

This is identical to the `foo` above.

Comment: if you just write the following in the swi terminal : member(Num, [1,2,3]), writeln(Num), fail, it writes the 3 numbers and false. Why in this case the predicate member is changing the number on each fail, and in my case it isn't?

Comment: @DavidNunes Because you don't have `fail` in your predicate definition, do you?

Comment: @DavidNunes It is one thing to observe what a program does; another thing to know why; and another thing to understand how to write other programs that do other things.

Comment: I don't have a fail but the program eventually fails, as you can see in the trace. After that fail shouldn't he go back and choose another Num, under the member predicate?

Comment: @DavidNunes When something "fails" all variable bindings since entering the context where the fail happens are undone. In the case of the toplevel this is OK because you get the answers printed out anyway.

Comment: @DavidNunes Some basic reading on how "he" does his thing won't harm. You must have gotten some recommended reading or something, haven't you?

Comment: so what should I do for that to happen in my program? Should I change the A each time it fails?

Comment: @DavidNunes As I said, I don't know what you are trying to achieve. There are no magic words that will make your program do what you wish, you need to explain it.

Comment: I want to find a way that does_something is called with the next Num in A, after failing, I really thought that the code, as I have it, would work, but it doesn't and I have tried so many other things that I run out of ideas to implement this

Comment: @DavidNunes You are not describing what you want to do, you are describing how you _think_ you should do it. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @DavidNunes A probable fix is to not use member, instead just take the first argument from `A`, add it to the set (?) in `B`, and give the rest of `A` and the new `B` to the recursive call. But this is just a very wild guess.

Comment: I just described what I want to do. I want the predicate to be called with another number from a list after it fails with the first number. Sorry if I am not being clear. BTW, shouldn't we stop commenting ?

Comment: @DavidNunes What does it mean, "with another number"? Should you pick every number from `A` only once? If so, why don't you just sort `A` and be done with it? Or do you mean something else? Have you heard of "pseudo code"? It might help if you wrote down the algorithm you have in mind in pseudo code, or even Python.

Comment: @DavidNunes The point is, if I understand what you are after, you want to keep on picking one element from the first argument, insert it into a set (represented as a sorted list), and keep on doing this until your set fulfils a requirement. I am a bit uncertain, because if this is what you are doing, your example will always fail anyway, so I must be missing something important.

Comment: I am sorry to put those dummy predicates: does_something and correct. Those are not the ones I want to but they are not relevant because my does_something REALLY has to receive a Num. Iam sorry that I am making you lose your time... the "append" was just an example

Comment: The situation that you described, I think you got what I want.

Comment: @DavidNunes See the edit at the bottom of my answer. Not sure if it helps but maybe it gives you a useful idea.

Comment: well, thanks for the time spent, and sorry for having bored you. I will keep trying to solve it.

Comment: are you still here?